# How to add live stream source in Red5 IServerStream?

Tags: video, streaming, server-side, live, red5

### The problem

I have created and started Red5 server-side stream in my custom application based on oflaDemo in this way:

```
serverStream = StreamUtils.createServerStream( app , "mystream" );

// repeats /streams/prometheus.flv from oflaDemo several times (20sec):
serverStream.addItem( SimplePlayItem.build( "prometheus" , 0 , 20000 ) );
serverStream.addItem( SimplePlayItem.build( "prometheus" , 0 , 20000 ) );

// now I want to add "camsource" stream, wich is published from Flash client:
serverStream.addItem( SimplePlayItem.build( "camsource" , 0 , 20000 ) );
...
serverStream.play();
```

prometheus.flv plays 2x nicely, but when times comes for "camsource" the result is:

`[Red5_Scheduler_Worker-3] org.red5.server.stream.ProviderService - Exception attempting to lookup file: ServletContext resource [/streams/camsource.flv] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`

**How can I create IServerStream that re-publishes user stream posted from flash client?**

I can both see flv stream and cam stream by `NetStream` `.play(...)` in Flash, but I cannot create IServerStream programatically to publish from live source.

The `comsource` publishing and `serverStream` are in the same Scope.

### My current working path

Due to [This response on Red5 group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/red5interest/3EhPcbTIY7c/AfnG4ddU2ZYJ), I have created my own ServerStream, in which I can push redirected/fake packets manually (I am not sure if this is done correctly):

```
public static class LiveTVServerStream extends ServerStream {

    public void manuallyPushPacket( IStreamPacket packet ) {
        for ( IStreamListener listener : getStreamListeners() ) {
            listener.packetReceived( this , packet );
        }
    }
}
```

Then I create such stream and register it in `appStart()`:

```
liveTVServerStream = new LiveTVServerStream();
liveTVServerStream.setScope( appScope );
liveTVServerStream.setName( "livetv" );
liveTVServerStream.setPublishedName( "livetv" );
// Add single starting video because ServerStream requires at least 1 item
liveTVServerStream.addItem( SimplePlayItem.build( "prometheus" , 0 , 20000 ) );
liveTVServerStream.start();

IContext context = scope.getContext();
IProviderService providerService = (IProviderService) context.getBean( IProviderService.BEAN_NAME );
providerService.registerBroadcastStream( scope , "livetv" , liveTVServerStream);
```

Then, if my "news reporter" (video source from webcam by Flash) starts broadcasting, I redirect packets to `liveTVServerStream`:

```
public void streamPublishStart( final IBroadcastStream stream ) {
   if ( !stream.getPublishedName().equals( "newsreporter" ) ) {
      return;
   }

logInfo( "News reporter connected - redirecting packets" );
    stream.addStreamListener( new IStreamListener() {
        volatile int dispatchedPacketCount = 0;
        volatile int ignoredPacketCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void packetReceived( IBroadcastStream newsReporterStream , IStreamPacket packet ) {
            if ( packet instanceof IRTMPEvent ) {
                dispatchedPacketCount++;
                if ( (dispatchedPacketCount % 50) == 0 ) {
                    logInfo( "Dispatched packets: " + dispatchedPacketCount + " ignored packets: " + ignoredPacketCount );
                }

                // delta-time calculations
                long t1 = newsReporterStream.getCreationTime();
                long t2 = liveTVServerStream.getCreationTime();
                long delta = t2 - t1;
                int t3 = ((IRTMPEvent) packet).getTimestamp();
                t3 += delta;
                ((IRTMPEvent) packet).setTimestamp( t3 );

                liveTVServerStream.manuallyPushPacket( packet );
            } else {
                ignoredPacketCount++;
            }

        }
    } );
```

### Current results

The log of Red5 console can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/dw2msY4Y).

"News reporter" flash works ok - sending video from webcam. But when I subscribe to watch "livetv" stream, there is no video. Flash parts works - tested it with `ServerStream` containing several .flv files in queue and Flash connected & streamed properly, like live TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just succefuly solved with `ClientBroadcastStream`:

```
liveTVClientStream = new ClientBroadcastStream();
liveTVClientStream.setScope( app);


IContext context = scope.getContext();
IProviderService providerService = (IProviderService) context.getBean( IProviderService.BEAN_NAME );
providerService.registerBroadcastStream( scope , "livetv" , liveTVClientStream );

liveTVClientStream.setPublishedName( "livetv");
liveTVClientStream.setName( "livetv");
```

Now we can set up listener on other stream and cast `IStreamPacket` to `IRTMPEvent` and put it into our main stream by `.dispatchEvent`

Comment: providerService.registerBroadcastStream( scope , "livetv" , liveTVClientStream ); after this line can clients actually start subscribing to this stream and receive data? I'm trying the code you listed and it doesn't work, dispatching works fine but it doesn't seem like clients can actually subscribe to the stream.

Comment: In my code, there are two scopes (app/scope) it is a mistake - use "app" everywhere - the same scope which you get in app initialisation from Red5. Grab my working live-tv class: http://wklej.to/NUqaZ, red 5 version 1.x propably

Comment: @killer_PL Can I ask after one year? :)  After your change in create class code to ClientBroadcastStream, is the same your initial call: (serverStream.addItem( SimplePlayItem.build( "livetv" , 0 , 20000 ) );) ?? How you put the live after fixed videos?

Comment: @MarceloGomes Unfortunatelly I've never combined static & live content... furthermore I not succeded in combinning live streams at all (lot of glitches, pauses, audio desynchros etc.)

Comment: @killer_PL Yeah, I have the same problem with Red5.  I´m trying to develop in Wowza, but I have some issues too with playlist and videos. We don´t have any server side stream reliable.